# How to remove a tree from a roof

Tags: roof, porch, tree

How do I remove this tree that fell down? It is partially on the roof.[image]

Comment: You probably want to call somebody, maybe your insurance company has a preferred provider. If you do something major like that yourself you might face liability or violate an insurance clause. I would cut it into sections from top-down, so that structure/weight never change dramatically at once. Once you get the top 1/3rd, maybe half cut off, the rest will probably swing back away from the house if the dirt under the root ball hasn't settled.

Comment: Be careful about cutting the top off the tree. The tree could stand back up.

Comment: This has unexpected dangers, Like @Lee Sam says.

Comment: @joe with a strong enough rope and a big enough machine it could be done, but unless you've got access to a crane or forestry machinery, forget it, or film it to add to the genre of truck/rope/tree fail videos

Comment: If you're desperate to reduce costs that aren't covered by insurance, first call the professionals, then ask if it would be any cheaper if you took some  branches off to save them some prep work - and listen to their answers

Comment: Can I wrap a rope around the upper trunk of the tree and yank the tree off the house?

Comment: Everyone is being very cautious because we don't want nothing to squash you, and be responsible for that. So a few thoughts: no branches = less weight and leaves one log, clear unobstructed. May upright tree. Easier to trim from roof in smaller sections till at roof intersect, maybe able to lift drop off roof at that point perhaps, or pull lift away from house. Better idea is pros, but if you have no choice, slowly and carefully.

Comment: @ChrisH: Wouldn't the professionals say "no" to avoid liability?

Comment: @Brian - The smaller less experienced tree services may say *no*. A good tree service will have factored the risk into their prices.

Comment: Been cutting trees for over 40 years.  First thing I would do with that tree is call professionals in.

Comment: @Brian they might well do. And if they did, and didn't want to consider the hypothetical case of some branches disappearing while they weren't on site, I'd listen to them, but maybe get a 2nd opinion. I may have a slight advantage over some people here - I'm in the UK where we're less litigious the USA, plus I could probably find someone through contacts

Comment: Funny. I'm reading this while listening to the chainsaws of the pros I called in to remove a big limb that fell on my roof yesterday afternoon. It fell while I was 20 feet up on scaffold on the other side of the house installing siding, so it's not like I'm a "call a pro for everything" kinda guy. This one was big enough and precarious enough that I didn't want to get hurt or cause structural damage. Earlier this summer, I lived dangerously as I took down a completely dead tree right next to the house. It was small and I was able to cut it into 5-7' chunks to bring it down with ropes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The conventional way to deal with this type of serious problem is to call in some tree service professionals. They know all the proper techniques to safely remove a fallen tree and may even have a crane truck that can be used to hoist pieces of the tree as it is cut apart.

Tree removal is dangerous work and you should not attempt this on a DIY basis unless you know exactly what you are doing and have experience.

Comment: Yep, and someone that knows exactly what they are doing doesn't ask this question. Some situations demand calling in the big guns, this is one of them.

Comment: This is the right answer, too many videos on youtube show "the consequences of inexperience - I find it fun to pause and predict the outcome...

Comment: @SolarMike what would you predict the outcome to be if I used a rope or a chain to pull the tree off of the roof?

Comment: @joe that will depend on the size of your skyhook...

Comment: @joe at a minimum, additional damage to the house and possibly personal injury. Seriously, call your insurance company ASAP and let them pay for the work. It's just not worth it, and anything you do _could_ give them reason to deny a claim, especially if your attempt to remove it causes more damage.

Comment: DIY tree work is a great way to get killed. Factor that into your cost analysis. I'm moderately good with a chainsaw, but no way I'd be tackling that mess. It's very easy to have things go very, very wrong in a hurry.